# How do you change the font Aptana Studio 3.5.0 editor tabs?

Tags: aptana3

My Aptana Studio just automatically updated to 3.5.0...the font size on the edit tabs is too big.

I cannot find a setting anywhere in the Preferences menu to change the UI Theme Font Sizes and theme colors.

My Theme is set to "Light Studio".

Does anyone have some config file magic to tweak the UI themes?   I'm not talking about code editor colors here - rather the Tabs and sub windows that make up the Aptana/Eclipse app.

Thanks Much!
Don

Comment: Pretty sure it is under Preferences > General > Appearance > View and Editor Folders.

Comment: Do you mean the labels / tabs in the GUI ? I want to decrease those!

Comment: Same here. I can't stand the huge tabs lables. I'd also like to reduce some of the spaces in the menu bars and the status bar. How can one edit the themes?

Answer (score 2):

Tested in Windows 7: open the folder

```
%APPDATA%\Aptana Studio 3\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.2.v20140221-1700\css
```

find the css file related to your theme (for example `e4_default.css` is the default theme) and customize the rule `CTabItem`, for example:

```
CTabItem {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an open bug. You can follow it at https://github.com/aptana/studio3/issues/235

Answer (score 0):

If you go Window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts->View and Editor Folders, then choose 'Part title font' (for tabs, etc.) or 'View message font'. Clicking on them will show a description of what that property applies to. The other items within the "View and Editor Folders" section only let you change the colour.

I had to restart Aptana for the changes to actually be displayed.