# Aptana using very large fonts in program tabs

Tags: aptana3

I'm a Linux newbie and started using Aptana as my development IDE. I love the features. The only problem I'm facing is that the fonts used in the program tabs are very large and out of proportions. I tried changing all kinds of parameter in the properties window but no luck. Does anybody know how to change the font size. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

It looks an [open bug](https://github.com/aptana/studio3/issues/235), but there are some answer this question:

[How do you change the font Aptana Studio 3.5.0 editor tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070014/how-do-you-change-the-font-aptana-studio-3-5-0-editor-tabs)